# CSV example for translation service in Google Play Console

Tags: android, localization, translation, google-play-console

I built my first mobile game using Unity and localized it for a few known languages using localization tool created by my own. However, I decided to have a bit more languages and wanted to translate app using Google Play Console Translation Service. Unfortunately, I stuck with CSV file.

Does anyone have an example of CSV file that tool is asking for please? Or maybe any other solution?

`Upload your strings.xml file to upload your user interface text if you use Android Studio for development. Upload a CSV file if you use any other tool for development. A CSV file must be encoded in UTF-8 format, and have string IDs and text to translate columns without a header row.`

Comment: Any help with that? I can't find and understand the CSV format

Answer (score 1):

The following XML file worked for me. If the XML is invalid, they'll inform you right away when you upload it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

        <string-array name="inventory">
                <item>Rewind</item>
                <item>Switch</item>
                <item>Mirage Filter</item>
                <item>Holy Grenade</item>
        </string-array>

        <string name="app_name">Gravity</string>

        <string name="rewind_desc">Got trapped in the space-time continuum? Rewind time back to the beginning and start over</string>

</resources>
```

FYI: [resources/string-resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard back from translators yet, but by trial and error, this file format was at least accepted by the UI:

- UTF-8
- Comma as separator
- No header row
- Column1 stringID
- Column2 OriginalText
- No extra columns*
- Fields quoted with double quotes

Like this:

```
arno@brick ~ $ cat polsk.csv 
"Adminlagre","Adminlagre"
"AlleVerktøy","Alle verktøy"
"BortkomneVerktøy","- Bortkomne verktøy -"
"GarantienUtløpDen","Garantien utløp %0"
"ReservasjonerSenere","Reservasjoner senere"
"SkjulteVerktøy","- Skjulte verktøy -"
"ukjentleverandør","(ukjent leverandør)"
```

*It seems uploading a csv with 3 columns is accepted too (unsure what that results in), but 4 columns didn't work…